# Find two functions $ f,g: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, trigonometry, periodic-functions

Given a function $\sigma: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which satisfies the following properties$(x\in\mathbb{R}, n\in \mathbb{N}):$

$$\sigma(n)=0, \sigma(x+1)=\sigma(x), \sigma(n+\frac{1}{2})=1$$
Find two functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $g(x)\neq0$ for all $x$ such that $\sigma(x)=g(x)(f(x)+1)$.

---

I have tried:

We have $\sigma(n)=0, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$
$$\Rightarrow \sigma(1)=\sigma(2)=\cdots=0$$
And $\sigma(x+1)=\sigma(x)\Rightarrow \sigma(x)$ is periodic function with period $=1$.

$\sigma(n+\frac{1}{2})\Rightarrow \sigma(\frac{3}{2})=\sigma(\frac{5}{3})=\cdots=1 $

$\sigma(x)=g(x)(f(x)+1)$ with $g(x)\neq 0$
Since, we have periodic function, so we will use trigonometric function for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

…………………………

Please kindly help me on this.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  Why not take $g(x)=1$ and $f(x)=\sigma(x)-1$?

Comment: Yeah how can I find $\sigma(x)$

Comment: You were given $\sigma (x)$, there is no need to find it.

Comment: Given that $\sigma$ you want to find $f,g$ such that $\sigma = gf + g$ with $g\neq 0$. So you can take any $g\neq 0$ and define $f:= \frac{\sigma}{g} - 1$.

Answer (score 1):

This diagram shows the set of points that are defined by the description you have given
: zero for integer values and 1 at the mid-points.

[image]

You need a curve that will pass through these points, and you are right to think that something trigonometric will do the task.

You should be aware that one obvious candidates is $\sigma(x)=\sin^2 (\pi x)$

Let $g(x)=1$ as suggested in the comments and let $f(x)=\sin^2 (\pi x)-1$ and then you have $\sigma(x)=g(x)(f(x)+1)$

Pick any periodic function. $g(x)=0.4 \sin^2 (\pi x) + 0.1$ has the characteristics you require since $0.1 \le g(x) \le 0.5$. You will then need to change $f(x)$ to $f(x)=2 \sin^2 (\pi x)-1$ to keep your peaks at $1$.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, how about the case $g(x)\neq 1$ and $g(x)\neq 0$. How can I find $g(x) $ in all general functions

Comment: Pick any periodic function. $g(x)=0.4 \sin^2 (\pi x) + 0.1$ has the characteristics you require since $0.1 \le g(x) \le 0.5$. You will then need to change $f(x)$ to $f(x)=2 \sin^2 (\pi x)-1$ to keep your peaks at $1$.